# JQuery replacing special characters

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to replace all instances where an escaped register (®) symbol appears on a content managed website on page load. Basically, my problem is that this code does not work:

```
function replaceText() {
    $("*").each(function() { 
        if($(this).children().length==0) { 
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('&reg;', '<sup>&reg;</sup>')); 
        } 
    });
}
```

but this does:

```
function replaceText() {
    $("*").each(function() { 
        if($(this).children().length==0) { 
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('test', '<sup>&reg;</sup>')); 
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Put an example, including HTML code on http://jsfiddle.net/. It's possible that the &reg; character is not represented using `&reg;`.

Comment: For debugging purposes, have you tried printing the contents of `$(this).html()` to the console for each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(document.body).html($(document.body).html().replace(/&reg;|®/g, "<sup>&reg;</sup>"));
```

This also replaces more than one symbol in a given object which your original code did not.

FYI, you don't have to look in every element individually.  You could just look in the HTML of the body and replace all there as long as you don't think this pattern would legitimately occur in an HTML attribute and as long as you are doing this before attaching any event handlers.

If you want to traverse each element individually, you can use this replace logic with your original code like this:

```
$("*").each(function() { 
    if($(this).children().length==0) { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&reg;|®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')); 
    } 
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DqdwX/

Comment: This'll remove any events already registered on any of the elements! Be sure to run it before attaching any events,

Comment: @gdoron - what `$` in the regex?

Comment: this: `(/&reg;|®/g,...` Sorry meant `&`

Comment: @gdoron - is `&` a special character in a regex?  I don't see it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and the fiddle works.

Comment: @JosephSilber - good point.  I added that point to my answer.

Comment: These all work when placed directly in the HTML file, but not in an external JS file. Both are UTF-8. Any ideas what could be causing that?

Another quick note, @jfriend00 the $(document.body) suggestion works, but breaks the Jquery slider on my homepage. The other suggestion works but replaces itself when placed in the HTML file, and then throws an "Invalid regular expression" into the console.

Comment: @Brizian - Are you trying to run it before the HTML is there?  If you're including them from an external JS file with a `<script>` tag, put the `<script>` tag at the very end of the HTML body so it can run after the HTML has been parsed.  Or, run it on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have the <script> right at the end of the body, and am running it on $(document).ready(). Still no luck. I've even removed all my other jquery to test for conflicts and still no luck.

Comment: @Brizian - not much I can do without seeing your actual implementation to debug.  I know of no reason why an external script file would be different for this purpose as long as you're sure the document is loaded before you try to change it.

Comment: @jfriend00 The `$(*).each` suggestion is working well enough for me to use it for now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Put the ® character into your javascript regex:

```
$("*").each(function()
{ 
    if ( ! $(this).children().length )
    { 
        $(this).html(function(el, html)
        {
            return html.replace(/®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>'); 
        });
    } 
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh9f6/

---

**P.S.** As mentioned by @jfriend00, if you know that you won't have this special character in any attributes (for example in `alt`), and you're doing this *before binding any events to any of your elements*, then you don't have to loop through it all. You could just do it once on the body, and it should replace all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for instances of the ® character. If you're using a text editor that wont allow you to inline `®`, you could use the JS escaped unicode equivalent:

```
'\u00ae'
```

Regex would help with this:

```
...replace(/\u00ae|&reg;/g, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that the character is literal in the HTML source. Then the escape notation `&reg;` doesn't match. Use this:

```
...replace(new RegExp('(&reg;|\u00AE)', 'g'), '<sup>$1</sup>');
```

`\u00AE` is the Javascript-escaped notation for Unicode codepoint U+00AE, aka ®.