# find and wrap every instance of a text character in a span using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, text

We want to find every instance of a character (specifically, `•`) on a page, then wrap it in a span so we can style them. They could be within all sorts of elements, multiple times, and all over the DOM: `<nav/>`, `<h1/>`, `<p/>`, etc.

We've tried one method found here related to matching a string and wrapping a span around it, but it seems to only match and wrap the first instance within any given element and ignore any subsequent instances within the same element. For example, for `<p>•</p> <p>•</p>`, both get matched and wrapped, but `<p>blah • blah • blah • blah</p>`, only the first gets matched and wrapped.

Here's what we tried:

```
$('*:contains("•")').each(function() {
   if($(this).children().length < 1)
      $(this).html($(this).text().replace('•','<span class="bullets">•</span>'))
});
```

Not sure if it has something to do with the `if` line... that's the only part that we're fuzzy about. Not particularly invested in this approach, however, so if there is something cleaner, let's hear it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgn6E/)

```
$('body:contains("•")').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        $(this).parent().html(function (_, oldValue) {
            return oldValue.replace(/•/g, "<span class='bullets'>$&</span>")
        })
    }
});
```

Try avoid using `*`. probably even `body`. Try using the outermost container as possible.

This should also work

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FKs6c/)

```
$('body:contains("•")').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 1) { //Look for only element Nodes
        $(this).html(function (_, oldValue) {
            return oldValue.replace(/•/g, "<span class='bullets'>$&</span>")
        })
    }
```

[Node Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)

Comment: Indeed, they both work. Thank you! Is one preferable to the other for any reason? When you suggest avoiding the use of "*"... I assume that's to minimize unnecessarily plowing through branches of the DOM?

Comment: I would probably suggest you to use second one, because it avoids a parent() selector. also try avoid using `*` because it will be a expensive operation since you are looking at all the element in the DOM including your script tags in the head etct etc. Instead you can scale it down to a parent containing element which you thing will have these char to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("*").each(function() { 
    if($(this).children().length==0) { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/•/g, '<span class="bullets">•</span>')); 
    } 
});
```

This answer is based of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010301/jquery-replacing-special-characters)

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3C7R/1/)